# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

This is the code :

```
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
      Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "****@gmail.com", "****");
      System.out.println(store);
      Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
      folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");
      folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

      System.out.println("Message Count: "+folder.getMessageCount());
      System.out.println("Unread Message Count: "+folder.getUnreadMessageCount());


           Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();  --> here the code stops.

      FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
      fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
      folder.fetch(messages, fp);

      for (int i = 0; i< messages.length; i++) 
      { 
          System.out.println("From:"+ messages[i].getFrom()); 
          }
```

The code gives out the following excption and stops at the point shown.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
>       at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.MessageCache.getMessage(MessageCache.java:129)
>       at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.getMessage(IMAPFolder.java:1394)
>       at openReports.OpenReports.main

Comment: getMessageCount are printing correclty so it connects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I added activation.jar to buildpath and the problem is solved.

So i used 2 jars java-mail-ima.** .jar, activation.jar (for further referebces).

Comment: Note that `javax.activation` is included in JDK 6 so if you use a newer JDK you won't need the activation jar.

Comment: Yeah .. That helped. It reduces the number of jars.. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Martin if we not used activation jar with higher JDK version. Still it shows no class found.

Comment: Note that this was removed again from Java 9 onwards. You will get the same error again after upgrading to JDK 9 or greater.

Comment: This showed up for me in the R language using the `rJava` library. I wonder how I can port this solution there...

Answer (score 46):

In case you use maven you can add manually

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My project used ant. Just needed to add `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/activation.jar"/>` to the `.classpath` file.

Comment: same for gradle ->    implementation 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'

Comment: Just for completeness, here's the artifact on sonatype with code for all build systems: https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1/jar

Answer (score 4):

I solved a similar NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource problem in a mixed Java/Scala project by switching to Java 8 (it was Java9 by default).

Discussion: https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

On jdk 1.8 I solved this problem by reinstalling jdk and check path in JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME