# How to add javax.activation.DataSource to App Engine devserver?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, blobstore, appengine-maven-plugin

**tl;dr:** How do I add the `javax.activation.DataSource` dependency to a server run through the App Engine Maven plugin?

I'm using the [App Engine Maven plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven) to deploy to a local App Engine server, and I'm trying to use the Blobstore API to upload a file. I'm using Java 11.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>io.happycoding</groupId>
  <artifactId>blobstore-test</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <!-- App Engine currently supports Java 8 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.71</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="<%= BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().createUploadUrl("/submit") %>" 
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

      Enter some text:
      <br/>
      <textarea name="text"></textarea>
      <br/>
      Select a file:
      <input type="file" name="image">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

**SubmitServlet.java**

```
package io.happycoding.servlets;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/submit")
public class SubmitServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("data submitted");
  }
}
```

**Command to run the local server:** `mvn appengine:devserver`

I can successfully run a local server, and I can see that the form is rendered correctly, including the Blobstore URL.

However, when I submit the form, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:115)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:108)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 57 more
```

Some Googling reveals quite a few questions about this problem:

- [Migration to JDK 11 has error occure “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52921879/873165)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource on wsimport Intellij java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46920461/873165)
- [What is the replacement for javax.activation package in java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46493613/873165)
- [NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8186395/873165)

The answers to these questions suggest adding a combination of these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I've tried adding each of these, and I've tried adding all of them. But no matter what, I still get the above error.

I understand **why** this is happening: Java 8 included the `javax.activation.DataSource` class, and it was subsequently removed. So since I'm using Java 11, that class is missing. But none of the dependencies I've tried so far seem to provide the missing class, possibly because I'm using the App Engine Maven plugin instead of running my own server?

How do I add this dependency to a project that uses the App Engine Maven plugin?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue after switching to Java 11, but using Java 8 for compiling the app engine project. The only way for me to resolve the issue on the local is to switch back to Java 8.

Comment: A clarification - When I include the activation-1.1.1.jar using the maven dependency, the error changes from `javax.activation.DataSource` not found to `javax/activation/DataContentHandler` not found.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

as you pointed out, but my expectation is that you're getting the NoClassDefFound error because the javax.activation classes aren't getting added to the war by maven. I still mostly do my jar/war/ear building with Ant for this very reason: more verbose, but less magic. If you look in your project's /target folder you should be able to see the war file: if you do a `jar tf <warfile>` you should be able to see all the jar files added to WEB-INF/lib, and this will tell you if it is adding the activation jar.

Looking at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin, the recommended sample includes this plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

before the `appengine-maven-plugin` entry in the build section of your pom. I'd put that in and then see if it properly builds the war.

Comment: I have the same issue, and tried your recommendation, but it didn't help. I can see the activation-1.1.1.jar in my WEB-INF/lib, but still get he error the same error. I'm using jdk-11.0.2.jdk when I get the error. Switching back to jdk1.8.0_231.jdk resolves the issue.

Comment: This one is because Java 9 deprecated javax.activation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java.activation-summary.html). You'll need to manually add it to your POM if you're using Java 9 or higher.

Comment: I've added it to the POM and confirmed that it's included in the WEB/INF/lib, but it still doesn't work. In addition, I also added the plugin which you mentioned, but that didn't help either.

Comment: This still works 11 years later :)

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine doesn't support Java 11. It only supports Java 8.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm asking how I can deploy **locally** with a later version of Java. Is there some official documentation that says this is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I switched back to Java 8 on local environment. On AppEngine it works.